# arm-elf-gcc and Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin, arm, elf

I recently updated to the most recent version of Cygwin (1.7.23), and what used to be a functional 'arm-elf-gcc' compiler seems to now be broken. In particular, no matter what input I supply the command, it complains that there are no input files:

```
$ arm-elf-gcc foo.c
arm-elf-gcc: no input files

$ arm-elf-gcc --help
arm-elf-gcc: no input files

$ arm-elf-gcc -v
arm-elf-gcc: no input files
```

Any ideas or suggestions as to why this could be happening? A Google search for 'arm-elf-gcc no input files' reveals little as to the cause. Thanks!

Comment: I would use a *mingw* compiler.  You need the compilers *cygwin* libraries to match your compilers.  I haven't had any issue with  *mingw* cross compilers and you can use them in the *cygwin* shells.  What is the advantage of a *Cygwin* cross compiler?

Comment: The research project that I am currently working on uses Cygwin, and it would take some doing to transfer over.

I apologize, but I do not completely understand your suggestion: Are you suggesting that I use arm-elf-gcc within mingw?

Comment: You could try that, too. But the real problem is usually the `cygwin1.dll` - be sure to have only one version in your `PATH`.

Comment: The *mingw* `arm-elf-gcc` will use native Windows system calls and execute faster.  It won't require the `cygwin1.dll` and it should be a drop in replacement.  **Cygwin** makes it easier to compiler *nix code on Windows; it generally doesn't give superior run-time.

Comment: Thanks, @TurboJ! That worked. The folder that contained the arm-elf-gcc executable also contained a cygwin1.dll, which clashed with the one in the 'bin' subdirectory of Cygwin. Out of curiosity, why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TurboJ mentioned in the comments to the original question, there were two conflicting versions of the cygwin1.dll. The folder that contained the arm-elf-gcc executable also contained a cygwin1.dll, which clashed with the one from the 'bin' subdirectory of Cygwin. I merely replaced the former with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Kother says, If you Installed Gnu arm and checked install cygwin.dll and cygwin 32 version,this problem will happen

so just go to your X:/gunarm/bin/ and rename cygwin.dll to cynwin.dll.bak,And everything will to alright